# Replace everything after last character in URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code which replaces the current URL using JavaScript:

`window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace(/\/?$/, '#/view-0'));`

However if I have a URL like:

`domain.com/#/test` or `domain.com/#/`

It will append the `#/view-0` to the current hash. What I want to is replace EVERYTHING after the last part of the URL including any query strings or hashes.

So presume my regex doesn't handle that... How can I amend it, to be more aggressive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax may help:

```
location.href.replace(/[?#].*$/, '#/view')
```

It will replace everything after (and together with) `?` or `#` in the string with `#/view`.

Comment: The replace works fine. But this no longer causes the page refresh like my code does... Any ideas why?

Comment: @Cameron You may try to assign the value back to `location.href`, i.e. `location.href = location.href.replace( ... )`. It should perform the redirect to the desired URL.

Comment: If the URL already has a hash in it and then I run this replace code, it sees it as a hashchange and therefore doesn't call a full refresh... If I do: `window.location.href = window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace(/[?#].*$/, '#/view-0'));` then it does the redirect but ends up at undefined in the URL.

Comment: @Cameron No, no. You should use either `location.replace` or `location.href = ...`, you shouldn't combine both. Just write the following: `location.href = location.href.replace(/[?#].*$/, '#/view')`.

Comment: In fact even your code in your comment is seen as a hashchange rather than a page redirect if a hash already exists...

Answer (score 1):

```
(^[^\/]*?\/)(?:.*)
```

Use this.Replace by \1 then your string

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sA7pZ0/28